# My Recursive loop gives me a Stack Overflow error even I think I have an exit from the loop

Tags: java, recursion

I am just a Java beginner and I'm trying to do a Minesweeper program. It's nearly finished but I want to do a method that opens also the adjacent squares if the opened square is a "0"

this is the code. For some reason it produces half the results I want and then pushes out an StackOverflowError.

variables:

```
finalA = buttons row
finalB = buttons column
buttons = button containing mine etc.
value = value showing mines adjacent to the square
rows = total rows
columns = total columns
```

And here is the code:

```
public static JButton[][] zeros(int finalA, int finalB, JButton[][] buttons, int[][] value, int rows, int columns){

    int a,b;
     //I found a reason for one Stack Overflow already. It was because when there was 2 zeros adjacent the code started to "jump inbetween them". I don't know why this didn't fix the whole problem.
    int[][] zeroOpened = new int[rows][columns];

    for (a = 0 ; a < rows ; a++){
        for (b = 0 ; b < columns ; b++){
            zeroOpened[a][b] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(a=0 ; a<3 ; a++){
        for(b = 0 ; b<3 ; b++){

            if(value[finalA-1+a][finalB-1+b] == 0 ){

                buttons[finalA][finalB].setText("0");
                zeroOpened[finalA][finalB] = 1;
                //this produces the error. The first part blocks Out of bounds exception, at least I think so. Second part doesn't work. It works for a while and then produces StackOverflow.
                if(finalA-1+a < rows && finalA-1+a > 0 && finalB-1+b < columns && finalA-1+b > 0 && zeroOpened[finalA-1+a][finalB-1+b]!=1)
                {
                    zeros(finalA-1+a,finalB-1+b,buttons,value,rows,columns);
                }


        }else{
            if(finalA-1+a < rows && finalA-1+a > 0 && finalB-1+b < columns && finalA-1+b > 0)
            {
                 buttons[finalA-1+a][finalB-1+b].setText("" + value[finalA-1+a][finalB-1+b]);

            }
        }
    }
    }

    return buttons;
    }
```

Comment: PLease start with refactoring so the code is readable before we can help you to debug it.

Comment: Even simply renaming some variables would help. What does the string "finalA" have to do with the idea of a row number?

Comment: I think you are applying the recursive call to the `[finalA][finalB]` cell itself, not just its neighbors. Is that deliberate? Does that chain of calls ever end? Also, `finalA-1+b > 0` should be `finalB-1+b > 0`

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess as to the error (I only sort of understand the code):

Your checking

```
 zeroOpened[finalA-1+a][finalB-1+b]!=1
```

in the if statement before you call zeros() again is not how it should work. Note that everytime you call this method, that method call begins with a new zeroOpened array and it's set to all 0s.

Try moving the zeroOpened array into the method parameters or make it a field. If that was a little vague, this is what I think your program does:

1. Okay, the user clicked on a square with 0 neighboring mines.
2. Then, by recursion, I'm going to check for 0s neighboring this 0.
3. So, I enter the zeros() method
4. In the zeros() method, I create **a new array zeroOpened**, which is supposed to store all the zeroes that have been shown. This is wrong because it doesn't take into account zeros you might have opened before in a different instance of this method. Basically, for each method call, you have a different zeroOpened array, which is causing your problem. You should only have one zeroOpened array, so make it a field or put it as a parameter in the zero method.

Again, disclaimer, I couldn't understand completely what's going on. For more efficient debugging, make sure you understand all your code and print some stuff to see if it makes sense (such as the indicies of the 0s you are opening).

Comment: Yes, you need to reuse the zeroOpened array between recursions.
Passing it as a method parameter should work. It could be initial passed as null, and initialized using "if(zeroOpened == null) zeroOpened = new int[rows][columns];"

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow is coming due to recursive call made in the below piece of code.

```
 if(finalA-1+a < rows && finalA-1+a > 0 && finalB-1+b < columns && finalA-1+b > 0 && zeroOpened[finalA-1+a][finalB-1+b]!=1)
                {
                    zeros(finalA-1+a,finalB-1+b,buttons,value,rows,columns);
                }
```

You are invoking function zeros() recursively. Either optimise your code or increase stack size in VM arguments